# how to change the color of the route on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to change the color of the line on google map when I serach the root. I want to make it like in the picture. I want to change it from this default picture [default line route](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C40.737102,-73.990318%7C40.749825,-73.987963%7C40.752946,-73.987384%7C40.755823,-73.986397&size=512x512&sensor=false) to line with red color like in this picture [color of route](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C40.737102,-73.990318%7C40.749825,-73.987963%7C40.752946,-73.987384%7C40.755823,-73.986397&size=512x512&sensor=false).
I use Google Maps JavaScript API V3. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

See answer [how to change the color of route in google maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022702/how-to-change-the-color-of-route-in-google-maps-v3)

When you create the directionDisplay object

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    polylineOptions: {
       strokeColor: "red"
    }
});
```