# Google maps route polygon on top

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

As continuing from previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35622032/75799

I have many polygon, which they cross each other or get on top of each other.

I wanted to put current active route on top of all the other route, so the color of the polygon shows green on top.

If you check following image, the active polygon is underneath other polygon.
[image: active is on bottom]

This will set color change on active route.

```
directionsRenderer2.setOptions({
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: 'green'
    },
    map:map
  });
```

Comment: These are not Polygons but Polylines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### Z-Index
>
> The order in which this **polygon** is drawn with respect to other overlays, including **Polylines**, **Circles**, **GroundOverlays** and **TileOverlays**, but not **Markers**. An overlay with a larger **`z-index`** is drawn over overlays with smaller z-indices. The order of overlays with the same z-index value is arbitrary. The default is 0.

So you could achieve that using `setZIndex()`, take a look at **[Polygon Public Methods Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there z-index on setOptions? like it is for map

Comment: Yes, you should try it `zIndex`.