# Google map API- display alternative routes with distance on info window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map and I am bit stuck at one point. I want to display alternative routes for my source and destination point. Currently I am using the code which is working perfectly and displaying correct result but the only the problem is that this code displaying `infowindow` for all routes with distance and time. And it needs to be differently colored for alternative routes..

Please help me out.

```
var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                optimizeWaypoints
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
            };
            directionsService.route(request,
                function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {                    
                    var step=2;
                        for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
                            new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                                map: mapObject,
                                directions: response,
                                routeIndex: i
                            });                         
                            stepDisplay.setContent(response.routes[i].legs[i].steps[step].distance.text + "<br>" + response.routes[i].legs[i].steps[step].duration.text + " ");
            stepDisplay.setPosition(response.routes[i].legs[i].steps[step].end_location);
            stepDisplay.open(mapObject);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm confused as to what is your exact problem. The title of the post is **display alternative routes with distance on info window** but then you mentioned ***but the only the problem is that this code displaying infowindow for all routes with distance and time***. You also mentioned ***And it needs to be differently colored for alternative routes..***. 

If I understand it correctly, do you want to show an `infoWindow` only on the **main route**? And for the alternative route (lines) to have a different color?

Comment: I need two helps.
1)I need infowindow(distance and time) for all routes(alternative and main routes)
2)In all routes line should be different colors

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed your code as much as I could (*not really that experienced with JS*). So I'm gonna go on ahead and try to address the concerns on your comment.

1. `InfoWindow` for **all** routes

Based on the code snippet you provided, the `for loop` already iterates over the `response.routes`. In here, I see you are already setting an `InfoWindow` (*showing distance and time*), based on the `route`:

```
stepDisplay.setContent(response.routes[i].legs[i].steps[step].distance.text + "<br>" + response.routes[i].legs[i].steps[step].duration.text + " ");
stepDisplay.setPosition(response.routes[i].legs[i].steps[step].end_location);
stepDisplay.open(mapObject);
```

-- It made me wonder as to why you still specified this as a problem. Then it hit me, is it that the only `InfoWindow` shown here is for the **last** route? If so, your probably not setting it to the map properly. So I looked around and found this [JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcde/3/) where I can try out if it's possible to show multiple `InfoWindows`. I just added the code where you include an `InfoWindow` like so:

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var step = 1;
            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow2.setContent(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].distance.text + "<br>" + response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].duration.text + " ");
            infowindow2.setPosition(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[step].end_location);
            infowindow2.open(map);
```

-- when you open the JSFiddle Sample above, just add the code snippet like above, below the `directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);` and it will show something like this:

[Multiple InfoWindow Map Screenshot][1]

2. Route lines should be **different** colors

For this concern, I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023573/6124253). From the answer:

*You can specify the color of the line when you create the DirectionsRenderer, using the optional DirectionsRendererOptions struct.*

Here's a part of the snippet in the answer:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "red"
    }
  });
```

I tried it out and this is how it looked like:

[Route Different Color Screenshot][2]

How you set the color of each route is up to you though.
Hope this helps. Good luck. :)

**PS: Included the Screenshot links in the comments.***

Comment: Screenshot links :)
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/32uo2.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CWRna.png

Comment: I think this post might also be helpful for you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648228/adding-infowindow-on-google-directions-route